# How to get the name of the calling module in Terraform

Tags: terraform

How can I access the name of the parent/calling module from within its child module.

Alternatively how can I get the filename of the calling module from within its child module?

e.g.

```
module "test_parent_module" {
    source = "./child_module"
}
```

```
module "child_module" {
    locals {
        // What could I use here to get parent module name?
        parent_module_name = module.parent # Should output "test_parent_module"
        // What could I use here to get the parent module's file name?
        parent_file_name = module.parent.filename # Should output "test_parent_module.tf"
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: There isn't any way of getting the module caller at runtime. You could get at the path from where Terraform is being ran by using `path.cwd` or `path.root` but that won't help you if you have nested modules and only want the parent and not the root module. Can I ask what you're trying to achieve with this? There might be a better way to do it instead.

Comment: This is currently not possible, but indeed would definitely be useful. It also exists in Puppet (`caller_module_name`), which is a really similar DSL with a really similar functionality for what is termed "module". Just this morning I was thinking again about putting in a feature request for this.

Comment: In my case the idea is to use the names of the config files in a declarative way. So the end user can just set the names of the file correctly and I can automatically use that to configure the Module.

Comment: This is intentionally not possible in Terraform because it would be surprising for a module's behavior to change just because the caller chose a different name for it. The name of a module is private to the calling module and nothing outside of that calling module should know or care about it.

Comment: If a module needs some sort of namespace or prefix to use to ensure that it can generate unique names in a remote system then it should declare a separate input variable for that prefix and be clear in the documentation which namespace that prefix is intended to be unique within, because remote systems will have a different definition of "unique" than Terraform does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. This type of inheritance hierarchy does not work for terraform. I would recommend passing variables instead. (Though it seems like there are other problems in your config if you are relying on the terraform file name so you might want to reexamine your code structures)

```
module "test_A_module" {} // what you had as parent
```

```
module "test_B_module" {
    source = "./child_module"

    module_name = "test_A_module"
    file_name = "test_A_module.tf"
}
```

```
module "child_module" {
    locals {
        module_name = var.module_name
        file_name = var.file_name
    }

}
```